# Throw and Catch in c++

Tags: c++, exception

(c++)So my throw code is like
`throw "No paper"`
And my catch code is
`catch(const char *txt ){}`
My question is why we are using a pointer to define the catch type and why char, can't we use something like
`catch(string txt){}`
I just learn exception handling and can't figure out why they used a pointer.
here is the [code](https://github.com/Krissny/cpp/blob/master/2_exceptionHand.cpp)!

Comment: Please provide a full example. To answer your question what you throw is a `const char array` and not a `std::string`. That is why you cannot use it

Comment: I doubt C has exceptions. Why the tag [c] was shown up?

Comment: If you want to catch `std::string` you have to throw one, e.g. `throw std::string("No paper")`

Comment: Have you learned already how strings work in C++ and how there are two different approaches of representing them, C-style null-terminated `char` sequences and `std::string`? If so what exactly is suprising about `const char*`? It works the same if you were passing the literal to a function instead. The only difference is that `catch` matches the type (more or less) exactly and doesn't consider conversions like a function call would. Is that last part what you want to ask about?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I just learned exception handling in c++ but can't understand why they used a pointer, I have provided the code , thanks for help

Comment: @AlanBirtles oh sorry, i will edit it

Comment: @user17732522 okay i understand now why they used char but the thing that i don't understand is how catch is processing the pointer

Comment: @KrishnaNandYadav I don't know what you mean with "_processing the pointer_". It doesn't do anything with it aside from initializing it.

Comment: Who wrote the code? Who is "they" ? You say its your code but then ask why "we" / "they" use a pointer.

Comment: @digito_evo you are awesome, it really clears it out and is exactly what I was seeking, thank you, I am new to stack overflow and I  don't know how to upvote the answer here, thanks again : )

Comment: @KrishnaNandYadav You can find the answers down below. Some people (mee too ^^) have a tendency to answer questions they perceive as simple in the comments instead of writing an answer. You can upvote and accept the answer if you like. See also this help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number uhh, i wrote  that code while learning exception handling from a youtube video to use it as notes later , and by they I mean the youtuber and c++ community, I am not a native english speaker so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you throw a *C string literal* like "No paper" you are actually throwing a **pointer** of type `const char*` and not an array of characters. This is how C++ works.

In other words, a string literal automatically decays into a `const char*`. It doesn't magically turn into a `std::string` or something like that when the `catch` parameter receives it.

And technically speaking, it's usually more efficient to throw an 8 byte pointer rather than to throw a 32 byte `std::string`. The bigger the size of an object is, the more costly it is to copy it around during the exception handling process.